# how to use decision in exponential for solver using c#

Tags: c#, ms-solver-foundation

In my application i'm using solver.In this i created a `Decision` function that is working fine. But i want to use `Decision` function in `Math.Exp` function. For better understanding refer source code below,

```
using Microsoft.SolverFoundation.Services;
using Microsoft.SolverFoundation.Solvers;

SolverContext context = SolverContext.GetContext();
Model model = context.CreateModel();

Decision sv = new Decision(Domain.RealNonnegative, "decision");           
model.AddDecision(sv);  

model.AddConstraint("limits", 5 <= sv <= 20);

model.AddGoal("Result", GoalKind.Minimize, (1 - Math.Exp(sv));//here i'm getting exception
```

Please guide me how to use solver decision in `Math.Exp` function. This one required for my project requrement.

Comment: Can you tell us the details of the exception? Like Exception Type or Exception Message

Comment: Basically in Math.Exp(double d) , the parameter should be double data type value , but i'm giving Decision type variable inside it, so that it is giving unhandled exception

Comment: @shivcena please post the complete exception message, including its call stack. It's easy to do, just call Expression.ToString(). Neither the question nor the comments make much sense.

Comment: Also explain what you are trying to do. `Math.Exp` has nothing to do with Solver, it's just .NET's exponential function. Why would you want to pass an object as an argument to it and what would you expect as answer?

Answer (score 0):

> As per the reference in google for Math.Exp() function we have to use double as a parameter.

Comment: Please use the *Post answer* button only for actual answers. You should modify your original question to add additional information.

Comment: BTW there is no reference for any .NET class in Google. Do you mean the documentation of AddGoal? Or Math.Exp?

Answer (score 0):

Try using: `Model.Exp()` instead of `Math.Exp()`